# How do I reliably stop a background process with node.js / gulp?

Tags: node.js, background-process, gulp

I'm using nodejs+gulp to orchestrate building and testing my website. As part of the end-to-end tests I want to start a separate RESTish API server (not written in Javascript).

I'm aware of node's `child_process` module, but how do I hook that up so the child gets killed when my gulp run terminates (possibly with an error) / restarted when one of its source files changes?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal

Comment: @coma The existence of `child.kill()` is not the problem. The problem is hooking a callback into gulp/node so that I can reliably stop the child process if the parent exits / gets killed / dies with an error.

Comment: If the parent exits the children will follow, no?

Comment: Anyway, this is not related to Gulp itself, is just a Node task that you can implement using the child mechanism it already offers, you can send messages to this child process from parent at any time, and well, you know when the testing task is over right?

Comment: @coma It'll get a SIGINT if I kill the parent with ^C, but otherwise, no it won't. In any case I did find `process.on('exit', function () {…})` (and `.on('SIG*',…)` which should do what I want.

Comment: … however, the problem is that node helpfully hangs around in its idle loop after my gulp task is done, waiting for the subtask to finish – _before_ calling the exit hook which is supposed to kill the task.

Comment: did you find a solution for this yet? I have a similar problem with PhantomJS   processes spawned with `child_process.exec()` - eventually one process hangs and blocks the whole event loop